# Restoring windows in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am having a hard time restoring a window after it has been minimized.

Minimize works fine, but i am trying to open the window back up.. `self` restores but Vodka_Frame doesn't.

Here is my code:

```
    def minimizeProgram(event):
        self.Iconize()
        Vodka_Frame.Iconize()


    def maximizeProgram(event):
        if self.IsIconized()=='True' or Vodka_Frame.IsIconized()=='True':
            self.Iconize(False)
            Vodka_Frame.Iconize(False)
            self.Show(True)
            Vodka_Frame.Show(True)
            self.Raise()
            Vodka_Frame.Raise()

    #### Catch the minimize event and minimize both windows.
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_ICONIZE,minimizeProgram)
    #### Catch the maximize event and maximize both windows.
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK,maximizeProgram)
```

What am i doing wrong? How can i get my windows back! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're doing wrong without a small runnable example. However, I created the following simple script that works for me:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)


########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="Test")
        panel = MyPanel(self)

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.toggleIconize, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(5000)
        self.Show()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def toggleIconize(self, event):
        """"""
        if self.IsIconized() == True:
            print "raising..."
            self.Iconize(False)
            self.Raise()
        else:
            print "minimizing!"
            self.Iconize()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Basically it just minimizes and raises itself every 5 seconds. I am using Python 2.6.6 and wxPython 2.8.12.1 on Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: how would you raise it without a timer and a time binder?

Comment: As the other fellow mentioned, you can make the second frame a child of the main and it should work. I think you could catch EVT_ACTIVATE or EVT_MAXIMIZE and raise the second frame that way as well.

Comment: This question might help us get on a better level of communication.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923906/wxpython-window-maximize-restore

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between your frames is not clear, but if you make the other frame child of the main one (i.e. specify the main frame as its parent when creating it), then it will be minimized and restored automatically when the main frame is minimized or restored, without you having to do anything special.