# wxPython Window Maximize/restore

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

After i minimize my window, how can i get it back up?

The `Iconize()` must be mandatory.

```
import wx

class AAAA(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Untitled',size=(450,395))

        def minimizeProgram(event):
            print 'minimized'
            self.Iconize()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ICONIZE,minimizeProgram)


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = AAAA(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply call [wxWindow::Iconize(false)](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_top_level_window.html#ae461559192e33ef111c3f147999a26bf)

Comment: Where abouts would i place it without getting stuck in a continuous loop?

Comment: Plenty of options. Simplest is probably to set a flag before calling `Iconize()` yourself and avoid doing anything in the event handler if it's set. You could also unbind the event before calling `Iconize()`. Or you could examine the event object in the handler to see if the window is being minimized or restored.

Comment: A better question would be:

"If i had two windows and they were both minimized, how can i restore one of the windows by restoring it's counterpart?"

Comment: I don't see what is the question about. If you have anything specific to ask, please do ask it, but AFAICS you have all the necessary information to do what you want.

Comment: I realize i can capture an event to minimize two windows at the same time, but i need to learn how to maximize two windows at the same time.

One window has no menu and frame whatsoever, so it cant be minimized on its own.

Its a college project, we have to build a futuristic IDE.